# showing a div content after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi there i'm trying to show a hidden div when scrolling down from the top of the browser page, like the Accordion function. What i'm using here is this Code:

```
HTML:-
// Visible DIV
<div class="firstBlock">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetuer adipiscing.</p>
</div>
 // Hiddden DIV
<div class="textBlock">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetuer adipiscing.</p>
</div>
// Visible DIV
<div class="secondBlock">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetuer adipiscing.</p>
</div>

CSS:-

.textBlock {
  text-align: center;
  height: 104px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.textBlock p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding: 10% 5%;
  line-height: 20px;
}

jQuery:-
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $(".textBlock").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".textBlock").stop().fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

but it needs some modification in order to work like Accordion-Function.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @User1979 it's working http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/b7yomjd0/1/

Comment: i know its working, but could we animate the fadeIn or fadeOut to work like Accordion?

Comment: @User1979 Use `.animate()`.

Comment: @User1979 : I suggest using [WOW](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) and [Animate.CSS](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) , WOW is the one that make the div reveals when the user reach to it by scrolling. And animate is a css stylesheet that have animations like fadein and fadeout

Answer (score 0):

If you want the accordion effect you should use the `slideDown` and `slideUp` functions ([docs here](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)), like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/b7yomjd0/3/